# Subir imagen a servidor con ajax y php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy realizando una página web. Para enviar datos a unas funciones de PHP, estoy utilizando JQuery.

Este es el formulario

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="1px" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Ficha</th>
        <th>Programa</th>
        <th>Nivel de formación</th>
        <th>Fecha inicio</th>
        <th>Jornada</th>
        <th>Ambiente</th>
        <th>Aprendices</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="agregar_ficha" type="number" name="ficha"></td>
        <td><input id="programa" type="text" name="programa"></td>
        <td>
            <select id="agregar_nivel_ficha" name="nivel">
                <option value="0">Nivel</option>
                <option value="Operario">Operario</option>
                <option value="Técnico">T&eacute;cnico</option>
                <option value="Tecnólogo">Tecn&oacute;logo</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="date" id="agregar_fecha" name="inicio"></td>
        <td>
            <select id="agregar_jornada" name="jornada">
                <option value="0">Jornada</option>
                <?php
                while ($jor=mysqli_fetch_array($b)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $jor['id_jornada'] . "'>";
                    echo $jor['nombre_jornada'];
                    echo "</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="agregar_ambiente" name="ambiente">
                <option value="0">Ambiente</option>
                <?php
                while ($am=mysqli_fetch_array($d)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $am['num_ambiente'] . "'>";
                    echo $am['num_ambiente'];
                    echo " - ";
                    echo $am['dependencia_ambiente'];
                    echo "</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="file-upload" class="subir">
                <img src="../imagenes/excel.png" id="excel">
            </label>
            <input id="file-upload" name="aprendices" onchange='cambiar()' type="file" style='display:none;'>
        </td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="agregar" id="agregar">Agregar.</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Este es el JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function obtener_datos(){
            $.ajax({                        
                type:"POST",                 
                url:"subirfichas.php",
                success: function(data)             
                {
                    $('#resultado').html(data);               
                }
            });
        }
        $(document).on("click", "#agregar", function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var data=$("form").serialize();
            alert(data);
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"subir_fichas.php",
                data:data,
                success: function(data){
                    obtener_datos();
                }
            });
        });
    });
    function cambiar(){
        var pdrs = document.getElementById('file-upload').files[0].name;
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = pdrs;
    }
```

Este código me toma todos los resultados, exceptuando el archivo a subir.
Sòlo me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para que AJAX me envíe el archivo a PHP.

Código PHP7:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$ficha=$_POST['ficha'];
$programa=$_POST['programa'];
$nivel=$_POST['nivel'];
$fechainicio=$_POST['inicio'];
$jornada=$_POST['jornada'];
$ambiente=$_POST['ambiente'];
$porciones=explode("-", $fechainicio);
$archico=$_FILES["aprendices"]["name"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente debas reemplazar el `var data=$("form").serialize();` por `var data = new FormData();`. Ejemplo:

```
var datos_form = new FormData($("#ID_DE_TU_FORMULARIO")[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    type: "post",
    data : datos_form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(){
    console.log('todo ok!');
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: ¿Eso me sirve para todo el formulario, o sólo lo hago para que me tome el archivo? (Es un .csv)

Comment: Aún así, eso no me funcionó tampoco.